# netty how to receive callback after write has occurred with ChunkedWriteHandler

Tags: playframework, netty

We are trying to get the tcp flow control in the playframework to automatically passthrough so a backed up client just passes the backup downstream through our server using no resources on our server.  To do this though, we need a WriteCallback so we know when we write a chunk using netty, we are told when the chunk is actually written.  If it is not written, the callback is not called which takes up a little memory but we don't read any more requests anyways until the write has occurred.

So in playframework, I see this being called on the Netty ChunkedWriteHandler

chunkedWriteHandler.resumeTransfer();

What we really need is to pass it a callback so we know when the write is finished.  Is there any other method or any way to achieve this easily?  Perhaps, I can fork netty for the time being and add a callback somehow though this looks very complex.  Any ideas very welcome.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the playframework very well, but in netty you get a ChannelFuture returned when calling write(..). You can then add a ChannelFutureListener to the ChannelFuture to get notified once the write completes.